# Medical Usage of Cannabis dataset

Tags: data-request, data

I am looking for a dataset about the effect of cannabis on patients. I'm looking to put together a report on the effect usage of cannabis on patients. I'm in need of some raw data specifically on how cannabinoid products impact patients dealing with Alzheimer's, multiple sclerosis, and the hepatitis virus, cancer,.... Can you help me out if I could find such data online?